# How can you restart your Windows console?

Tags: windows-7, console

I would like to restart my windows 7 console. How do I do so?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Is an application, not a DOS itself. Sample close and open it again.

If you have a process that can not be stopped, try `Control+C`